# Uploading website files question

Tags: c#, deployment

When uploading modified files to a server (C# changes), should you always upload the whole website using an MSI?

Also, if you have uploaded a website and installed it using an MSI, do you need to upload the website.dll as well? Or does the MSI create it already?

Any comments will be appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: for published website you have to upload everything to server.
If you are just using build version then you can only upload the changed cs file. 
- MSI installer installed all compiled dll so you dont have to upload it saperately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET was designed to be setup via xcopy install (simple copying of files), so copying everything (upload) should work fine (this is what the website deploy option in visual studio does).

If you have an MSI of the website, it indeed should have the compiled dll in it (assuming you have created the installer correctly).

It really is a matter of convenience - what is more convenient for you?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Is it just for convienience or are there advantages to using an MSI?

Comment: With an MSI, you can setup IIS, change the registry, uninstall the website before installation and more... use only if needed.